# full path of input file to send mutliple attachments php

Tags: php

When retrieving the path from the input file, using $_POST, 
the path is being picture.jpg
and I need to have the full path i.e. C:/C:\Documents and Settings...\picture.jpg

what do i have to use ???

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no reliable way to determine this any more. The full path used to be sent along by some browsers in `$_FILES[xyz]["name"]`, but nowadays most browsers just send the original file name for security reasons.

Not even Flash based uploaders like [**SWFUpload**](http://www.swfupload.org/) can do this any more: See [**this forum discussion**](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/683).

Comment: It would be horrible if browsers did send out that information. +1

Comment: @karim79, yeah. They used to send it along until not too long ago, at least IE when you were a trusted site. It was great in a CMS, you were able to store the original location of an asset... it's a horrible security hole if allowed globally, but I really miss that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

you cant. Maybe creating a custom flash/applet that sends it. But not though normal html+php code.
You can try to get the value of the 'file' input and add to a 'hidden' something like this:

```
jQuery('#theform').submit(function(){
   jQuery('#thehidden').val(jQuery('#thefile').val());
   return true;
});
```

But im not sure, i guess it depends on the browser security and configuration let you get the filepath from it.

Comment: i just tested it, it returns only the filename